# Step by step how to install and configure Alfresco 5 from source code to be up and running on Tomcat

Tags: alfresco

I have already downloaded Alfresco 5 source code into eclipse. Is there any guide illustrates how to install and configure it to be up and running on Tomcat web server?

Comment: why would you wanted to do so - build everything from source?

Comment: I need to make some customization and code change.

Comment: alfresco supports.customization without changing source code.

Comment: Many peoples are making mistakes like this.So for people like that.Please keep in mind that "Most of the CMS are extendable without editing source code".

Comment: @KrutikJayswal Thanks a lot for this serious info.

Comment: Please give up if you found anything use full in stackoverflow

Comment: @KrutikJayswal I've already give you up. can you please make it answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many peoples are making mistakes like this.So for people like that.Please keep in mind that

**Most of the CMS are extendable without editing source code.**